# How to have differently formatted author names for some items in a citation list, using biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, formatting, citing

I am looking for some guidance on how to tweak the appearance of some citations. At the moment, the format in a MWE looks like this:

[image]

In general, I want the author list for articles and books to appear as they do in items 1. and 3. above (surname, initial). So far so good. However, now all authors appear in this format such as the second item "Education, D.". Since this is not a name/surname I would like to have this one appear as "Department for Education".

What's the best way to clean this up? Do I somehow need to add an exception everytime I have this kind of citation occurring? Or is there another option/field that I can make use of to do it automatically?

The code to produce the MWE is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
            style=numeric-comp,
            firstinits=true,
            sorting=none,
            doi=false,isbn=false,url=false,eprint=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}

\addbibresource{bibliography_list.bib}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\textbf{#1}}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}
\AtBeginBibliography{\raggedright}
\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\footnotesize}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{#1\adddot}


\begin{document}

Here is my first reference \autocite{horowitz1989art}, here is my second reference \autocite{DfE}, and finally my third reference \autocite{bloch2000measurement}. 

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

and the bib file looks like this:

```
@book{horowitz1989art,
  title={The art of electronics},
  author={Horowitz, Paul and Hill, Winfield},
  year={1989},
  publisher={Cambridge Univ. Press}
}

@online{DfE,
  author = {Deparment for Education},
  title = {Guidance for schools: coronavirus (COVID-19)},
  url = {https://www.gov.uk/government/collections/guidance-for-schools-coronavirus-covid-19},
  urldate = {2020-07-24},
  year = 2020
}

@article{bloch2000measurement,
  title={Measurement of the spatial coherence of a trapped Bose gas at the phase transition},
  author={Bloch, Immanuel and H{\"a}nsch, Theodor W and Esslinger, Tilman},
  journal={Nature},
  volume={403},
  number={6766},
  pages={166--170},
  year={2000},
  publisher={Nature Publishing Group}
}
```

Comment: The second entry has a *corporate* author. You must write it as `author = {{Deparment for Education}},` i.e., encase it in a doubled pair of curly braces. Otherwise, by the syntax rules of both BibTeX and biblatex, the author's name gets parsed as having `Department` as the given name, `for` as the von component, and `Education` as the surname.

Comment: Yes I see, thank you. Simple. When should one use this method versus the "organization" field?

Comment: When dealing with a corporate author, you should *always* use this method. This issue is separate from and independent from issues related to how the `organization` field should be handled.

Comment: Okay thanks for the advice. In that case, the link you provided does answer my question. Is it best practice to just leave this question here, or to delete it?